# Why the form is not in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place the signin form in middle of the page with flexbox:

```
<div class="auth-container">
  <form [formGroup]="signInForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input formControlName="username" matInput placeholder="Username">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="Password" type="Password">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-error *ngIf="true">
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">SIGN IN</button>
    <p>Form value {{ signInForm.value | json }} </p>
    <p> Form status {{ signInForm.status | json}} </p>

  </form>
</div>
```

the style:

```
.auth-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  form {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

the `align-content: center;` does not work and I do not figure out why. But `justify-content: center;` works.

Comment: You wrapping div is 100% height but 100% of **what**? The parent height (up the DOM chain) must be stated or calculable. Try using `100vh` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Add 100% height to `html` and  `body` to have a height reference for your container element (and thereby make the vertical centering work).

2.) Add `margin: 0` to your `form` to center it horizontally within its container:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.auth-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth-container">
  <form [formGroup]="signInForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input formControlName="username" matInput placeholder="Username">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="Password" type="Password">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-error *ngIf="true">
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">SIGN IN</button>
    <p>Form value {{ signInForm.value | json }} </p>
    <p> Form status {{ signInForm.status | json}} </p>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the html a bit to not get distracted...

Changing `flex-direction: column;` to `flex-direction: row;` seems to do the trick.

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.auth-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.auth-container form {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth-container">
  <form>
      <input formControlName="username" placeholder="Username">
      <input formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" type="Password">
 <button>SIGN IN</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [the magic of `margin: auto;`](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberAP/fgcarvxs/)

```
form
{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

If your form is the only child of the container it's better not to use `flex-direction: column;`, as there's no reason for that.

```css
html, body
{
  /* Don't forget to set your document width and height to 100% */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.auth-container {
  /* No need to change flex direction here */
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

form
{
  display: flex;
  /* You could use width: 50%,
     but I felt max-width is a better suit here
     for low resolutions */
  max-width: 50%;
  /* Infinite margin from all sides centers the block */
  margin: auto;
  /* This is needed for block to grow with max-width set */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* Handle edge cases with long text overflow */
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth-container">
  <form [formGroup]="signInForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input formControlName="username" matInput placeholder="Username">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="Password" type="Password">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-error *ngIf="true">
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">SIGN IN</button>
    <p>Form value {{ signInForm.value | json }} </p>
    <p> Form status {{ signInForm.status | json}} </p>

  </form>
</div>
```